# Tranformar array de objetos em apenas um array

Tags: php, array, objetos, conversão

Eu tenho um `array` com múltiplos **objetos**:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5750 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(16) "mail@example.com"
    ["key"]=>
    string(18) "email_client"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#5254 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(20) "gold"
    ["key"]=>
    string(19) "package"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#6074 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "senh4"
    ["key"]=>
    string(18) "password"
  }
}
```

E eu preciso que fique:

```
array = {
   email_client => mail@example.com,
   package => gold,
   password => senha
}
```

Eu tentei com `foreach` mas ele não acessa os objetos. Com o `array_walk_recursive` a resposta é a mesma. alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer converter Array de Objeto em Array Indexado, com chaves?

Comment: Mas o que pude perceber que a sua pergunta está um objeto de um maneira, e um exemplo de saída que não condiz, o titulo é uma coisa e a pergunta fala em outra, poderia ser mais claro sobre a pergunta. e retratar a realidade sua, para que tenha respostas a sua realidade.

Comment: Eu tenho varios objetos dentro de um array e cada objeto tem um 'indice'. array{ [0] => objeto { key : valor, value: valor} }

Comment: coloque esse array de objetos na sua pergunta e o resultado que deseja, por favor?

Comment: object(stdClass)#5750 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(16) "mail@example.com"
    ["key"]=>
    string(18) "email_client"
  } .   Esse é o objeto. Como pode ver no exemplo ele tem um indice no array.

Comment: Certo @IvanMoreira, mas, o resultado na sua pergunta não condiz com as chaves e juntar o array de objetos para um unico array associativo sem mudar as chaves não dá? entendeu?

Comment: Não? Eu só quero que o ["key"] => email_client e o ["value"] => mail@example do objeta sejam chave/valor do meu array exemplo email_client => mail@example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o array for ter sempre a mesma profundidade você pode fazer :

```
$array = array();
foreach ($arr as $obj){

$array[$obj->key] = $array[$obj->value];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que não usar os próprios objetos?

```
foreach($arr as $obj) {
    echo $obj->key . ': ' . $obj->value; 
}
```

Também é possível fazer *cast* para array na hora de acessar, se quiser muito usar a sintaxe de array (não vejo muito sentido nisso):

```
foreach($arr as $obj) {
    echo (array)$obj['key'] . ': ' . (array)$obj['value']; 
}
```